# Quick JQuery issue with sliding DIV

Tags: jquery, sliding

I need my sliding DIV to be automatically closed on page load, at the moment it is showing expanded, and also I want to slow the animaton down... at the moment its super fast even though i've set it to low. The code is below:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide('slow');
        $(".show_hide").show('slow');

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

 $(".slidingDiv").hide('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#form" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<a name="form" id="form"></a>
<div class="slidingDiv">

CONTENT BLAH BLAH

</div>
```

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fmhqW/ if this is too fast still, try setting a millisecond delay instead of 'slow'. Like .hide(2000) - this will be 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide('slow');
}, 2000);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BWqjp/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make the div hidden by style, or at least remove the slow parameter from div `.hide` call.

Regarding the speed, you can pass any number as parameter of `.slideToggle()` to determine how long the slide effect duration will be (in miliseconds).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show('slow');

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(2000);
    });

});​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S8qZh/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using fadeIn and fadeOut?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show_hide").hide();
    $(".slidingDiv").fadeOut('slow', function() {
         $(".show_hide").fadeIn('slow');            
    });
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zEnZx/

Comment: Using the `fadeOut` again at the end?

Answer (score 0):

`$().ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide()
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
      $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    })
});`